# While setting up Netbeans for C++ it shows build host not connected

Tags: c++, netbeans

I am trying to set up my Netbeans application for writing C++ programs, but whenever I create a dynamic or static project it shows "build host not connected".

How can I overcome this problem? I have already installed cywin64 terminal

Answer (score 0):

**Solve this problem  Using the Tool Collection List**

The Tool Collection list shows what tool collections are available to the IDE on the local host and on each remote build host. You can see the Tool Collections in any of the following ways:

```
Using the Services window:
```

1) Choose Window > Services,
 2) expand C/C++ Build Hosts and the host you are interested in.
 The Tool Collections node lists the tool collections available on the host.
   3) Use the Projects window: Right-click a project, 
select Properties, and click the Build category. You can select a tool collection to use for the project or click the button next to the Tool Collection list to open the Tool Collection Manager to set the default collection, and add or remove tool collections. This worked for me :)

```
                                         or 

Using the Options window: Choose Tools > Options > C/C++ > Build Tools. In this property sheet you can manage the tool collections after selecting the host in the Build Host list.
```

In each case, the Tool Collection list displays the collections found on the host currently selected in the Build Host list. The default collection is listed in bold type, and is selected for any new project you create using the build host. You can change the tool collection for a specific project in the project properties.